# ASP.NET : How to load user control from database and send parameter to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that contain user control name and the position in my page. In page load all of my panel in each position load a user control .
my position is like this :
[image: this image shows each user control place in specific cell of table in default page]
this is my code to load usercontrol name from DataBase and set them to their position like this image but I want to send parameter to each user control but HOW?

```
private void loadUCposition()
{
    string sql = "select ucname,positionid,StringParameter from Position p inner join modulename mn on p.modulid=mn.ucid" +
        "";
    DataTable dt = ADO.setDg_DataTable(sql);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string pos = row[1].ToString();
        string ucs = row[0].ToString();
        Panel p = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("p"+pos) as Panel;

        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        if (ucs.IndexOf(".ascx") > 0)
        {

            uc = this.LoadControl(ucs) as UserControl;
        }
        else
        {
            uc = this.LoadControl(ucs + ".ascx") as UserControl;
        }
        uc = this.LoadControl(ucs) as UserControl;
        p.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're referring to setting parameters to a user control, I imagine you mean setting values in the markup;

```
<myUserControl parameter1="1" parameter2="2" />
```

The syntax above is just wrapping. myUserControl is a C# class, and those parameters are variables of said class. (Although auto-generated classes)

To modify the position of a user control instance then is to access its variables and change them.

In your example:

```
uc = this.LoadControl(ucs) as UserControl;
p.Controls.Add(uc);
// Modify new instance's public member variables
uc.positionX = 123123;
uc.parameter1 = 1;
uc.parameter2 = 2;
```